# how to make angular routing path 'post/:id' and 'post/create' co-exist?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am using angular 9, here is my routing part.

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',component: PostComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '',redirectTo: '',pathMatch: 'full', },
      { path: 'post/:id', component: PostDetailComponent},
      { path: 'post/create', component: PostCreateComponent}
  ]
}];
```

when passed the routing path "/post/create", the component initialised is actually "post/:id" instead "post/create",

how would I do to make them work together ?

Comment: Can. you be more specific? Like can you show the route navigator function? If not navigating provide the routing module if possible

Answer (score 0):

The routing is based on the order of precedence. So the route defined above will be matched before the ones below. Try to reorder the routeing

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',component: PostComponent,
  children: [
    { path: '',redirectTo: '',pathMatch: 'full', },
    { path: 'post/create', component: PostCreateComponent},
    { path: 'post/:id', component: PostDetailComponent}
  ]
}];
```